# Show that this is indeed a differentiable manifold with boundary.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, manifolds

I want to show that the cylinder:

$$C = \{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + y^2 = 1, 0 \le z \le 1 \}$$

is indeed a a differentiable manifold with boundary, this means the following:

A subset $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a differentiable manifold of dimension $k$ with boundary if, for each $x \in M$, exists open sets $U \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a class $C^1$ function $f:U \to V$ such that:

1) $x \in V$

2) $f:U\cap \mathbb{H}^k \to V\cap M$ is an homeomorfism

3) for each $y \in U\cap \mathbb{H}^k $ the jacobian matrix has rank k

and $\mathbb{H}^k=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^k : \text{the k-th component is not zero}\}$

So I was thinking in $f$ as the function $f(x,y)=(x \sqrt{1-x^2},y$ but I don't know how to take $U$ and $V$ such that the conditions are satisfied (I was thinking $U=[0,1]$ and $V=(0,1]$ but I don't know if it may help).

Thanks a lot for your help in advance

**My way of writing the proof:**

I take the function as in the answer, since my definition requires the existence of two open sets $U,V$ then I choose $U=(0,2\pi)\times (0,1)$ then we note that $U \cap \mathbb{H}^2=U$, **Now, my question is** how to take the optimum $V$ for the definition requirements, because if I take $V=\{(x,y,z)\in R^3:|x|<1,|y|<1,0<z<1 \}$ the intersection $V\cap C$ is not what we need for the definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the parametrization 
$$ f(\theta,z) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, z ) $$
From here you have your Jacobian; clearly it always has full rank. 
Edit: For any interior point $x \in M$ on the cylinder, we have that
$$U = (0, 2\pi) \times (0,1) \quad \& \quad V= \{ x,y,z:x^2+y^2=1 , z \in (0,1)\} $$
or
$$U = (- \pi, \pi) \times (0,1) \quad \& \quad V= \{ x,y,z:x^2+y^2=1 , z \in (0,1)\} $$
will suffice. For $x \in M$ on the boundary, we have the half balls 
$$U = (0, 2\pi) \times [0,1) \quad \& \quad V= \{ x,y,z:x^2+y^2=1 , z \in [0,1)\} $$
or
$$U = (- \pi, \pi) \times [0,1) \quad \& \quad V= \{ x,y,z:x^2+y^2=1 , z \in [0,1)\} $$
for the bottom, and
$$U = (0, 2\pi) \times (0,1] \quad \& \quad V= \{ x,y,z:x^2+y^2=1 , z \in (0,1]\} $$
or
$$U = (- \pi, \pi) \times (0,1] \quad \& \quad V= \{ x,y,z:x^2+y^2=1 , z \in (0,1]\} $$
for the top.

Comment: Right, and $U,V$ ?

Comment: The definition doesn't mean a global $U$ and $V$. It means around every point $x$ on your manifold, you can find an open set with no "kinks". Which is true here since we may always take a ball of radius $\epsilon>0$ in the interior, and a half ball on the boundary.

Comment: Well, in the examples I have seen they always exhibit $U,V$, and I can figure out that $U=(0,2 \pi) \times (0,1]$

Comment: Probably to show you examples, but finding one example doesn't imply it's true. Consider a solid cylinder, this wouldn't be a differentiable manifold. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Well, I think it is right, just take the function on my post, then define $U=\{(x,y) \in R^2: |x|<1, |y|<1\}$ and $V=\{(x,y) \in R^2: |x|<1/2, |y|<1\}$, the think is the part of $H^2$ that is the think is wrong with this

Comment: What about $x=1, z=0$... That doesn't fit into your sets. Anyhow, im just trying to draw your attention to the definition to make you think about what it means. Cheers.

Comment: So, how do you write the complete proof?

Comment: Exactly as I wrote it when I first replied, you may choose to make it more formal with exact definitions of the balls. The reason why the solid cylinder isn't a differentiable manifold is because I can't take a half ball on the "kink", i.e. any point on $x^2+y^2=1$ and $z=0$ or $z=1$. I'd have to take a quarter of a ball. This implies that I cannot find a homeomorphism between $M$ and $\mathbb{H}^3$ there. Hopefully the definition makes slightly more sense now.

Comment: Ok, let me edit my post for a verification please :)

Comment: Ready, I have edited my post :)

Comment: Have a look at my post again...your proof is incomplete.